# Populate HTML table with 3 JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. I have a jQuery function below that allows me to populate a HTML table with 2 arrays `red,blue` however I'm struggling to add in another Array `green` into the function. Is it possible to just add in another array or do I have to do it another way?

```js
var red = ["apple", "cherry", "tomato"];
var blue = ["blueberry", "sky"]
var green = ["cabbage", "broccoli", "plants"]

var bodyString = '';
$.each(blue, function(index, blu) {
  bodyString += ('<tr><td>' + blu + '</td><td>' + red[index] + '</td></tr>');
});
$('.countriesTable tbody').html(bodyString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="countriesTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Capital</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi! *"however i'm struggling to add in another Array green into the function"*  What part are you stuck on? You have the `red` example, just...do the same thing. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I am confused by what you are asking? Are you saying you just want to add another table cell for the green array? If so, then just add it like you have with the red and blu one... what are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: It is hard for us to understand the issue. Is it just this: `<td>' + red[index] + '</td><td>' + green[index] + '</td>` ?

Comment: The arrays have to be the same length of course or use the longest array in the each and test there are items in the others

Comment: You're using blue array to loop through and also outputting the red array, that's bad practice unless your arrays are always going to be the same size?

Comment: Just as a side note: Instead of `blue`, `red`, and `green` arrays, it would make more sense to have a *single* array of objects, with `red`, `green`, and `blue` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var red = ["apple", "cherry", "tomato"];
var blue = ["blueberry", "sky"]
var green = ["cabbage", "broccoli", "plants"]

var bodyString = '';
$.each(blue, function(index, blu) {
  bodyString += ('<tr><td>' + blu + '</td><td>' + red[index] + '</td> +<td>' + green[index] + '</td></tr>');
});
$('.countriesTable tbody').html(bodyString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="countriesTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Capital</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You are missing "tomato" and "plants" and just posted my comment code

Comment: Sorry if you felt i cheated from your comments. But I swear I didnt read the comments before posting my own answer.I know what I wrote and what the output would be.The ques never said it wanted all the red and green elements. I earlier mentioned in answer to keep the length of blue array same as that of red and green, but then I edited my answer, thinking may be its the OP's requirement !

Comment: Not really cheated. Just unnecessary to answer with the comments given

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you MEANT to be doing - I added the answer since it was not straightforward to do what you wanted.

Improvement could be doing this in one pass and possibly use .map for the array

```js
var colours = {
  "red": ["apple", "cherry", "tomato"],
  "blue": ["blueberry", "sky"],
  "green": ["cabbage", "broccoli", "plants"]
}

var $header = $("<tr>"),
  cols = 0,
  bodyString = "";

$.each(colours, function(key, values) {
  $header.append($('<th/>').text(key));
  cols = Math.max(cols, values.length); // find the longest
});
for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) { // or use .map, but this is more undertandable for beginners
  bodyString += '<tr>';
  $.each(colours, function(key, values) {
    bodyString += '<td>' + 
      (values[i] ? values[i] : "-") + // ternary - instead of using if/else
      '</td>';
  });
  bodyString += '</tr>';
}
$('.fruitAndVegTable thead').html($header);
$('.fruitAndVegTable tbody').html(bodyString);
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="fruitAndVegTable">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```